# How to build an Expression for FullText Search with EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Given a `PropertyName` and a `Value` to search for how can I build an Expression to work with?

Outcome has to be `EF.Functions.Contains(PropertyName, Value)`.

In the end I am applying the expression to a `IQueryable`.

Thank you!

Comment: Question looks like developer task. What you have tried so far?

Comment: I've build this https://github.com/timewarp-it/xtentityframework/blob/main/xtEntityFramework/PredicateBuilder.cs and want it to support FullText Search in Line 115 if the Property has some Attribute. Unfortunately I was not able to find EF.Functions.Contains via Reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Contains` method for FullText search located in `SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions`

```cs
var PropertyName = "SomeProp";
var Value = "SomeValue";

var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeType), "c");
var propertyPath = PropertyName.Split('.')
    .Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.Property);

var callExpression =  Expression.Call(
    typeof(SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions),
    nameof(SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions.Contains),
    Type.EmptyTypes,
    Expression.Constant(EF.Functions),
    propertyPath,
    Expression.Constant($"\"*{Value}*\"")
);
```

Comment: Almost there! Looks like passing the PropertyName as string doesnt work. I have `x.PropertyName` as MemberExpression but using that directly throws "The LINQ expression 'x' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form (...)". Although the Result in Code ("DbSet<Person>()
    .Where(c => c.Firstname.Contains(\"d\") || DbFunctions
        .Contains(
            propertyReference: \"Lastname\", 
            searchCondition: \"d\"))
    .OrderBy(p => p.Lastname)") looks good! Do you have an idea what `EF.Functions.Contains` is expecting as `propertyReference`?

Comment: It expects only constant for PropertyName.  So you have to retrieve column name from `x.PropertyName`, probably from IModel.

Comment: I dont get it. While `people = people.Where(p => EF.Functions.Contains(p.Lastname, "Duck"));` works, `people = people.Where(p => EF.Functions.Contains("Lastname", "Duck")); does not work and throws `"The expression passed to the 'propertyReference' parameter of the 'FreeText' method is not a valid reference to a property. The expression must represent a reference to a full-text indexed property on the object referenced in the from clause: 'from e in context.Entities where EF.Functions.FreeText(e.SomeProperty, textToSearchFor) select e'"`.

Comment: My fault, you are right it may expect property, never used this function. Have you tried [Readable Expressions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers)? Anyway you have problem with parameters. From your code I cannot understand how it is extracted.